# Primeng MessageService instanciation blank page

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, primeng

i just downloaded the quickstart cli of primeNg for angular and added a second component for the chart (it's shipped with a ui component already) . did everything okay and when i save i get a blank page for the whole app not only the second component , it's only when i delet the constructor instanciation of MessageService that i get my app back , please help

the first component don't use MessageService
tried already to import from 'primeng/api'

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MessageService } from '../../../node_modules/primeng/components/common/messageservice';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chart',
  templateUrl: './chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chart.component.css']
})
export class ChartComponent implements OnInit {
  data = {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: 'First Dataset',
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
            fill: false,
            borderColor: '#4bc0c0'
        },
        {
            label: 'Second Dataset',
            data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90],
            fill: false,
            borderColor: '#565656'
        }
    ]
};

  constructor( private messageService: MessageService ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  selectData(event) {
    this.messageService.add({
        severity: 'info',
         summary: 'Data Selected',
        });
}

}
```

expected to get the chart like the documentation , but get blank error , same thing happened whet i used ng2-charts

Answer (score 1):

Just stumbled upon this problem myself, the fix was to declare MessageService as a provider in AppModule, correct import statement Is:

```
import { MessageService } from 'primeng/api';
```

AppModule:

```
providers: [ MessageService ],
```

Post created along time ago but maybe it can help someone else

Answer (score 0):

You should add your app.main.component.ts p-toast module like below.
Note: Key is so important here:

```
<p-toast key="tst" [baseZIndex]="50000"></p-toast>
```

Then you should call the message service with this key like below:

```
this.messageService.add({ key: 'tst', severity: 'success', summary: 'Başarılı', detail: 'Teklif Başarıyla Kaydedildi' });
```